# How to change background-image on <select> element

Tags: javascript, html, css

The problem is, I can put fixed background image, but I want it to be changed when I change currency

code:

```
<select id="from" class="recalculate flag-show" style='background-image: url(<?= url("assets/img/volopa/flags/gbp.png") ?>); background-repeat: no-repeat!important; background-position:left!important;'>
                    <option value="gbp" selected="">GBP - Pound Sterling</option>
                    <option value="eur">EUR - EURO</option>
                    <option value="usd">USD - US Dollar</option>
                    <option value="aud">AUD - Australian Dollar</option>
                    <option value="cad">CAD - Canadian Dollar</option>
                    <option value="chf">CHF - Swiss Franc</option>
                    <option value="dkk">DKK - Danish Krone</option>
                    <option value="hkd">HKD - Hong Kong Dollar</option>
                    <option value="jpy">JPY - Japanese Yen</option>
                    <option value="nok">NOK - Norwegian Krone</option>
                    <option value="nzd">NZD - New Zealand Dollar</option>
                    <option value="pln">PLN - Polish Zloty</option>
                    <option value="sek">SEK - Swedish Krona</option>
                    <option value="zar">ZAR - South African Rand</option>
                </select>
```

[Calculator location](http://volopa.borne.io/consumer-solution/)

I tried with css:
select#form option[value="usd"]{....}

but no changes.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why is this question tagged "javascript" and "php"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure this is possible with css alone.
You could add a simple snippet of `Javascript`. In this case I would probably use `data-attributes`.

I set up an example with `data-flag` and targeting it this way in your `css`.

```js
const from = document.querySelector('#from');

from.addEventListener('change', function() {
    this.dataset.flag = this.value;
});
```

```css
#from[data-flag="gbp"]{
  background: red;
}

#from[data-flag="eur"]{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<select id="from" class="recalculate flag-show" data-flag="gbp">
      <option value="gbp" selected="">GBP - Pound Sterling</option>
      <option value="eur">EUR - EURO</option>
  </select>
```