# Jquery Conditional Class add

Tags: html, jquery, css, conditional-statements

So I'm working on this small frontend project with some jQuery I wanted to do something where there is a list of names and if you click it, a class of "selected" should be added, but I want to remove that class if some other option is selected.
So suppose Name-1 is selected It gets a background Color Change, but If Name-2 is selected right after the background color for Name-1 should go away and add to Name-2, and I have multiple names so I can't make a function for every single option.
I was wondering if there is a easier way to do it.

HTML

```
 <ul class="names">
                    <li class="name selected">Name-1</li>
                    <li class="name">Name-2</li>
                    <li class="name">Name-3</li>
                </ul>
```

CSS

```
.selected {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67750214/how-to-change-background-image-on-select-element/67750693#67750693

Comment: That does make sense but the problem is that they are making use of Options rather than UL and LI(s) which is what I want for this project specifically.

Comment: @OutdatedDNZ is my answer below helps you ?

Comment: Understood that each name would have a different background. ***I have multiple names so I can't make a function for every single option***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
$("ul.names li").on("click", function(){
   $("ul.names li").removeClass("selected");
   $(this).addClass("selected");
})
```

**EDIT - explanation**
you select all the `<li>` tags by this selector `ul.names li` and manipulate them together, first you remove the `selected` class from all `li` tags by this `$("ul.names li").removeClass("selected");` and then you add `selected` class to the chosen `li` tag represented by the `this` key word

```js
$("ul.names li").on("click", function() {
  $("ul.names li").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");
})
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="names">
  <li class="name selected">Name-1</li>
  <li class="name">Name-2</li>
  <li class="name">Name-3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why the downvote, @OutdatedDNZ accepted this as an answer

Comment: @OutdatedDNZ do you need the colors to be changing ?

Comment: No that fine I accepted this as a answer and I didnt downvote it

Comment: @OutdatedDNZ thanks, yes I know you didn't downvote it

Comment: @OutdatedDNZ can you upvote also ? thx

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```js
$('.name').on('click', function() {
  $('.name').removeClass('selected').css('background','none');
  $(this).addClass('selected').css('background',$(this).data('bg'));
});
$('.name.selected').css('background',$('.name.selected').data('bg'));
```

```css
.selected {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="names">
    <li class="name selected" data-bg="green">Name-1</li>
    <li class="name" data-bg="red">Name-2</li>
    <li class="name" data-bg="blue">Name-3</li>
</ul>
```